# Strange requests being made to my site

Tags: hosting, requests

I've recently started hosting my dev site from my laptop and I see these requests being made on my domain. I've no idea what these are. Please help.

```
/avtomaticheskaya-blokirovkaautomatic-key-lock.html
/avtomaticheskaya-blokirovkaautomatic-key-lock.html
/barbelo.html
/batterylife.html
/blokirovka-prilozhenijadvanced-lock.html
/here-and-now.html
/imtalk.html
/here-and-now.html
/internet-brauzer-jb5.html
/mobile-weather-for-s60-third-edition-smartphones.html
/hidden-contacts.html
/ion-battery-timer.html
/internet-na-rabochem-stoletouchticker.html
/internet-na-rabochem-stoletouchticker.html
/happy-nap.html
/jbak-taskman.html
/kukushkacuckoo.html
/jbak-taskman.html
/freetimesync.html
/largetime.html
/legkij-kontrollight-control.html
/tvitter-klienttwim.html
/loshadinoe-licohorseface.html
/mazelock.html
/brauzer-ucweb.html
/world-time-and-temperature.html
/irc-klientphirc.html
/calc-sheet-lite.html
/calc-sheet-lite.html
/cclock.html
/vidzhet-shutka-pukupss.html
/christmas-theme-by-maple.html
/clock-screensaver.html
/colorsmusic.html
/conversation.html
/conversation.html
/dedit-text-editor.html
/dinamicheskaya-smena-fonapulsepaper.html
/wayfinder-earth-beta-north-america.html
/tema-simpsony-na-otdyxesimpsons-camping-theme.html
/talk-info-lite.html
/my-world-gps-tracker.html
/qeep.html
/mazelock.html
/mdictionary.html
/mecanto.html
/memoryup-personal.html
/metronome.html
/microsoft-silverlight-symbian.html
/mobile-info.html
/mini-blasterminiblaster.html
/mobilnaya-matematikamobile-maths.html
/mobile-cipher.html
/mini-carrom.html
/mobilnyj-brauzer-opera-mini-5.html
/monitoring-serdechnogo-ritmaheart-rate-monitor.html
/mr-lock.html
/multyashnaya-temacartoon-theme.html
/music-theme-by-blue-ray.html
/nauchnyj-kalkulyatorccalcpro.html
/perekati-poletumbleweed.html
/palo-theme.html
/nokia-energy-profiler.html
...
```

Comment: What does the host header say (if on exists) for the requests? That will likely answer the question as to its getting visitors and what site they mean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's likely that your IP address was previously used to host a website, and quite possibly, there is a domain name out there that still resolves to your IP (and now there's a bot out there looking to refresh its caches of those pages).

Do your logs have any more details about the host that was requested? Chances are if you look that up, it'll resolve to your laptops IP.

Comment: It turned out to be Google bot. I've updated my robots.txt. Thanks.

Comment: +1 nice explanation... I saw similar behavior for my new site on Amazon cloud. A little digging found that the IP was previously allocated to pinterest.com (yeah, I was paying for their popularity) !